# Will getMessage for new message force a reload in Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I can't find this in the documentation:

Suppose I have a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, if I call getMessage() for a property that I just added to the properties file, with another process, will this force a reload, as the property does not exists yet (is not cached), or will this throw an exception?

Do I have to wait for the next cacheRefresh until the property is accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will throw an exception until the cache times out. The last modified time stamp of the file is evaluated in `refreshProperties()` but this happens only after a the cache timeout.

If this is a web application, I suggest to create a web service that calls `clearCache()`. Your external process can then write new property files and invoke the service to force the refresh in a timely manner.